Why does filtering based on a condition results in an empty DataFrame in pandas?
I'm working with a DataFrame in Python using pandas, and I'm trying to apply multiple conditions to filter rows based on temperature values from multiple columns. However, after applying my conditions and using dropna(), I end up with zero rows even though I expect some data to meet these conditions.
The goal is compare with Ambient temp+40 C and if the value is more than this, replace it with NaN. Otherwise, keep the original value.
Here's a sample of my DataFrame and the conditions I'm applying:
data = {
    'Datetime': ['2022-08-04 15:06:00', '2022-08-04 15:07:00', '2022-08-04 15:08:00', 
                 '2022-08-04 15:09:00', '2022-08-04 15:10:00'],
    'Temp1': [53.4, 54.3, 53.7, 54.3, 55.4],
    'Temp2': [57.8, 57.0, 87.0, 57.2, 57.5],
    'Temp3': [59.0, 58.8, 58.7, 59.1, 59.7],
    'Temp4': [46.7, 47.1, 80, 46.9, 47.3],
    'Temp5': [52.8, 53.1, 53.0, 53.1, 53.4],
    'Temp6': [50.1, 69, 50.3, 50.3, 50.6],
    'AmbientTemp': [29.0, 28.8, 28.6, 28.7, 28.9]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'])
df1.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

Code:
temp_cols = ['Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3', 'Temp4', 'Temp5', 'Temp6']
ambient_col = 'AmbientTemp'

condition = (df1[temp_cols].lt(df1[ambient_col] + 40, axis=0))

filtered_df = df1[condition].dropna()
print(filtered_df.shape)

Response:
(0, 99)

Problem:
Despite expecting valid data that meets the conditions, the resulting DataFrame is empty after applying the filter and dropping NaN values. What could be causing this issue, and how can I correct it?

Please hardcode the data as code, so you have a minimal reproducible example that can be run.

What does condition look like?

@Mainland what is your ultimate goal? If you combine a mask and dropna, it would be much more efficient to directly use df[(df1[temp_cols].lt(df1[ambient_col] + 40, axis=0)).all(axis=1)] as showed in my answer.

Use DataFrame.where:
condition = (df1[temp_cols].lt(df1[ambient_col] + 40, axis=0))

df1[temp_cols] = df1[temp_cols].where(condition)

If need new DataFrame add DataFrame.reindex:
temp_cols = ['Temp1', 'Temp2', 'Temp3', 'Temp4', 'Temp5', 'Temp6']
ambient_col = 'AmbientTemp'

condition = (df1[temp_cols].lt(df1[ambient_col] + 40, axis=0))

filtered_df = df1.where(condition.reindex(df1.columns, fill_value=True, axis=1))
print(filtered_df)
                     Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Temp4  Temp5  Temp6  AmbientTemp
Datetime                                                                  
2022-08-04 15:06:00   53.4   57.8   59.0   46.7   52.8   50.1         29.0
2022-08-04 15:07:00   54.3   57.0   58.8   47.1   53.1    NaN         28.8
2022-08-04 15:08:00   53.7    NaN   58.7    NaN   53.0   50.3         28.6
2022-08-04 15:09:00   54.3   57.2   59.1   46.9   53.1   50.3         28.7
2022-08-04 15:10:00   55.4   57.5   59.7   47.3   53.4   50.6         28.9

How it working:
#mask
print(condition)
                     Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Temp4  Temp5  Temp6
Datetime                                                     
2022-08-04 15:06:00   True   True   True   True   True   True
2022-08-04 15:07:00   True   True   True   True   True  False
2022-08-04 15:08:00   True  False   True  False   True   True
2022-08-04 15:09:00   True   True   True   True   True   True
2022-08-04 15:10:00   True   True   True   True   True   True

#added Trues values in mask for missing columns - here `AmbientTemp`
print (condition.reindex(df1.columns, fill_value=True, axis=1))
                     Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Temp4  Temp5  Temp6  AmbientTemp
Datetime                                                                  
2022-08-04 15:06:00   True   True   True   True   True   True         True
2022-08-04 15:07:00   True   True   True   True   True  False         True
2022-08-04 15:08:00   True  False   True  False   True   True         True
2022-08-04 15:09:00   True   True   True   True   True   True         True
2022-08-04 15:10:00   True   True   True   True   True   True         True


Your condition is a DataFrame, if you want to select by row you should aggregate with any/all:
condition = (df1[temp_cols].lt(df1[ambient_col] + 40, axis=0)).all(axis=1)

Output:
                     Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Temp4  Temp5  Temp6  AmbientTemp
Datetime                                                                  
2022-08-04 15:06:00   53.4   57.8   59.0   46.7   52.8   50.1         29.0
2022-08-04 15:09:00   54.3   57.2   59.1   46.9   53.1   50.3         28.7
2022-08-04 15:10:00   55.4   57.5   59.7   47.3   53.4   50.6         28.9

If you want to mask the values, use where after reindexing:
df1.where(condition.reindex(columns=df1.columns, fill_value=True))

Output:
                     Temp1  Temp2  Temp3  Temp4  Temp5  Temp6  AmbientTemp
Datetime                                                                  
2022-08-04 15:06:00   53.4   57.8   59.0   46.7   52.8   50.1         29.0
2022-08-04 15:07:00   54.3   57.0   58.8   47.1   53.1    NaN         28.8
2022-08-04 15:08:00   53.7    NaN   58.7    NaN   53.0   50.3         28.6
2022-08-04 15:09:00   54.3   57.2   59.1   46.9   53.1   50.3         28.7
2022-08-04 15:10:00   55.4   57.5   59.7   47.3   53.4   50.6         28.9

